# ContentProvider implementation in Titanium Android Module

Tags: android, appcelerator, android-contentprovider, titanium-modules, titanium-android

Is it possible to implement a ContentProvider in a Titanium Android module?

I have the ContentProvider already written as a Cordova plugin for a hybrid/Cordova style app but I want to port it to Titanium. My problem is that I can't see how or where I can add the provider node and what value I can give the android:name attribute in the provider node.

Are there any examples of ContentProvider Titanium Android modules?